# Does a UITableView with 10000 items use the same amount of memory as one with 100?

Tags: uitableview

I wonder, does UITableView avoid filling memory with UIImage pixel data in a smart way?

Answer (score 0):

No, obviously loading more data is going to use more memory. You could load 10 images at a time to save on memory usage.